# How can I create a .deb file from my docker image?

Tags: docker

So I have attempted to dive into Docker and created my first image of a web app and can run it successfully.

How can I create a .deb file to send this out to people to install it on their systems?

Comment: Docker images themselves are meant to be what's distributed, they're not meant to be converted to .deb packages. You should look into publishing the image you created on [docker hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker images themselves are what should be distributed. Images are not meant to be converted to .deb packages. You should look into publishing the image you created on [docker hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/) or another container repository like [Amazon Elastic Container Registry](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/) or [GitHub Container Registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry) so people can `docker pull` and `docker run` your image.

If you don't want to use a container registry, you can always share your repository and `Dockerfile` so people can build it locally.

See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68253442/4676641) for a more reliable way but not "best practice" method to share Docker images. These methods all require Docker be installed.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the people who will be using this web app will not have docker installed. Can they still run those commands without docker installed?

Comment: Sadly, no, unless they have a container compatible client like [podman](https://podman.io/), [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) installed. Respectfully you might want to consider a different way of distributing your application if your clients don't have Docker. Docker will be required to run the images you create with it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to send an image to someone - without using a registry - is to use `docker save` to create a file containing the image. You can then send the file to the people that need it and they can restore the image using `docker load`.

Comment: (This is the Docker equivalent of emailing individual `.deb` files around and using `dpkg` rather than `apt-get` to install them; I'd do it only as a last resort in situations where you _can't_ run a Docker repository or use a pre-hosted one.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I agree. But I'd think it's more reliable than having people build the image from sources as suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: Rebuilding from source should be completely reliable as long as the source is available. Builds are meant to be repeatable. Of course, it's accepted that source is not always going to be available.